# How to remove the old Installation of Ubuntu

Tags: uninstall

I forgot my password and I decided to reinstall Ubuntu with the last version. Now, how can I get rid of the old version? I use VM Virtualbox as emulator.

I must say that I am and old COBOL developer and everything is new here for me.

Comment: You could recover your password. By the way, you can simply format those partitions related to the old installation and reconfigure the grub.

Answer (score 0):

Download the new system as an .iso file. Add this file to the list of Storage devices for this machine in Virtualbox.

Then, with the virtual machine powered off, adjust the boot order under Settings, so the machine will boot off the .iso instead of the hard disk. Then start the machine. It will ask you if you want to install the new Ubuntu over the old one. You want the "use the whole disk" option (unless there is some data on it that you want to keep).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to keep anything from the previous install, right-click on the virtual machine in Virtualbox, and click Remove.

Then create a new Ubuntu by clicking "new" and following the prompts. This makes things really easy if you are not comfortable with Virtualbox.